# How to properly add an image through JavaScript to a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am following along in a tutorial that creates a dynamic webpage. The webpage is supposed to show the time and an image that updates according to whatever hour it is. However, the way the instructor is inserting his image is new to me and I am not sure where I am messing up but no image at all is being displayed on the page.

````
    let today = new Date(),
    hour = today.getHours();

    if(hour < 12) {
        // Morning
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/Morning.jpg')";
        greeting.textContent = 'Good Morning';
    } else if(hour < 18) {
        // Afternoon
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/Evening.jpg')";
        greeting.textContent = 'Good Afternoon';
    } else {
        // Evening
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/Night.jpg')";
        greeting.textContent = 'Good Evening';
    }
}```

I get no error messages with the following function after calling it. However, no image is being displayed.
````

Comment: `Morning/jpg` is not a valid file. You probably want `Morning.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
url('../images/Morning.jpg')";
```

has to be a valid URL.  Let's say your HTML file was `www.example.com/foo/index.html`.  There would have to be a `www.example.com/images/Morning.jpg` file, or else you won't see anything.

This is especially true if your URL before was "Morning/jpg", as that's not a valid URL (well, technically it is, but it almost certainly isn't valid for your case).

Comment: I can get it to work if I copy the image location off the site I am using, but still am running into problems when trying to pull it from the saved location. It is saved in the following location: C:\projects\Dynamic Webpage\images

Comment: Fundamentally the issue is that your image isn't where your web browser thinks it should be.  Without looking at your computer though it's really hard to help beyond that.

Comment: is there another way to insert a saved image that might be easier?

Comment: It's not about the way you insert a saved image, it's about having an image with a working URL.  If you can't browse to the image's URL in your browser (without any code whatsoever) and actually *see* your image, it won't matter *how* you add the image to the page: it won't work.

Comment: Ok I think I am following along. However, I get confused when talking about the URL. I thought images saved on your file drive could not have a URL. I get you can copy the image location off the internet, but what if you take a photo yourself and want that pic inserted? Sorry if I seem like a newbie, just have run into this problem and have not figured it out yet. Thanks for the responses thus far.

Comment: Even files on your computer can have URLs.  However, those URLS start with `file://` instead of `http://`.  You can use file URLs when you're just developing on your own computer, but if you want to create websites that other people can see your images (and your HTML file) will need to be uploaded to a web host, at which point they will all have "real" (ie. HTTP) URLs.